# where can i find the refresh token for Google cloud speech api access token upload/download

Tags: android, access-token, google-speech-api

Access token for Google cloud speech api expires every one hour and currently i am requesting for new access token using my service account:

$ gcloud auth print-access-token

access_token

can this be done programatically? do we need refresh token for this? how to get refresh token and how to request for access token programatically?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the Google API Playground, that demonstrates the calls you make and the responses you'll need to handle, via your server. Your app will then request an access token periodically.

Comment: Do u mean it will be automatic there after? any source code needed? I am using Google API Playground to create access token for accessing gcloud basically for downloading. . but i have been doing from the browser only everytime...

Comment: You have to replicate the API calls demonstrated in the Playground on your server to generate the access tokens, which your app will request.

Comment: i dont understand how to do that. Right now i am using Playground and using the access token   from there and using in it my source code like this :

Comment: OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
       RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, new File("/storage/emulated/0/bank.flac"));
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket/o?uploadType=media&name=myObject")
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("authorization", ACCESS TOKEN HERE)
                .addHeader("content-type", "audio/flac")
           ...

Comment: how to automatically import the new access token from playground to my request header in source code?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think how else to explain it. The Playground is to demonstrate how the token calls work - it shows the http requests you will need to make and their responses. From your server, you need to make these calls directly to the API (not via the Playground) and pass the access token to your app.